Next.js Intercept Route displays on route a link is clicked from instead of first navigating to the parent route
I am new to next.js and am having trouble with intercept routes. What I am trying to achieve is a nested intercept route "latest/[slug]" that would display in a modal over the "latest" route template, however when there is a link from another route i.e. the homepage clicking on the "latest/[slug]" link here is displaying the modal over the homepage as opposed to navigation to "latest" and then displaying "latest/[slug]" in a modal there.
I am just trying to resolve the issues with the intercept route for now so there is no modal logic and I am just dumping the slug for the route.
Here is the code setup
Layout.tsx:
// Next //
import dynamic from 'next/dynamic'
import { draftMode } from 'next/headers'
import type { Metadata } from 'next'

// Sanity //
import { loadProjectsCount } from '@/sanity/lib/store'

// Components //
import Header from '@/src/components/header'
import Footer from '@/src/components/footer'

// Styles //
import '@/src/styles/global/_base.scss'

const LiveVisualEditing = dynamic(() => import('@/sanity/loader/LiveVisualEditing'))

const AppLayout = async ({
  children,
  modal,
}: {
  children: React.ReactNode
  modal: React.ReactNode
}) => {
  // Load the initial data for the projects count.
  const initial = await loadProjectsCount()

  // If there is no initial data, return null.
  if (!initial) {
    console.error('No data returned for projects count')
    return null
  }

  // Destructure the residential and commercial projects count from the initial data.
  const { residentialProjectsCount, commercialProjectsCount } = initial.data

  return (
    <div id="root">
      <Header
        residentialProjectsCount={residentialProjectsCount}
        commercialProjectsCount={commercialProjectsCount}
      />
      <main className="main">
        {children}
        {modal}
      </main>
      <Footer />

      {draftMode().isEnabled && <LiveVisualEditing />}
    </div>
  )
}

export const metadata: Metadata = {
  robots: {
    index: false,
    follow: false,
    nocache: true,
    googleBot: {
      index: false,
      follow: false,
    },
  },
}

export default AppLayout

@modal/(.latest)/[slug]/page.tsx:
const LatestModal = ({ params: { slug } }: { params: { slug: string } }) => {
  return <h1>{slug}</h1>
}

export default LatestModal

latest/page.tsx:
// Next //
import { draftMode } from 'next/headers'
import dynamic from 'next/dynamic'

// Sanity //
import { loadLatestListingPage } from '@/sanity/lib/store'

// Components //
const LatestListingPage = dynamic(() => import('@/src/components/pages/LatestListingPage'))
const LatestListingPagePreview = dynamic(
  () => import('@/src/components/pages/LatestListingPagePreview')
)

const LatestRoute = async ({ modal }: { modal: React.ReactNode }) => {
  // Load the initial data for the about page.
  const initial = await loadLatestListingPage()

  // If there is no initial data, return null.
  if (!initial) {
    console.error('No data returned for about page')
    return null
  }

  // If draft mode is enabled, return the preview component.
  if (draftMode().isEnabled) return <LatestListingPagePreview initial={initial} />
  return (
    <>
      <LatestListingPage content={initial.data} />
      {modal}
    </>
  )
}

export default LatestRoute

latest/[slug]/page.tsx
// Next //
import { draftMode } from 'next/headers'
import dynamic from 'next/dynamic'

// Sanity //
import { loadLatestPage } from '@/sanity/lib/store'

// Components //
const LatestPage = dynamic(() => import('@/src/components/pages/LatestPage'))
const LatestPagePreview = dynamic(() => import('@/src/components/pages/LatestPagePreview'))

const LatestArticleRoute = async ({ params }: { params: { slug: string } }) => {
  // Load the initial data for the about page.
  const initial = await loadLatestPage(params.slug)

  // If there is no initial data, return null.
  if (!initial) {
    console.error('No data returned for about page')
    return null
  }

  // If draft mode is enabled, return the preview component.
  if (draftMode().isEnabled) return <LatestPagePreview initial={initial} params={params} />
  return <LatestPage content={initial.data} />
}

export default LatestArticleRoute

I am sure there is something quite simple I am missing or is this not the right approach for this functionality?
I have tried moving the modal prop from the Layout file and calling that only inside that route expecting this would result in the modal only showing here, but I guess I am missing something with the way the AppRouter works where it is not matching /latest from /latest/[slug] and first navigating there but instead trying to access /latest/[slug] directly?
// Next //
import { draftMode } from 'next/headers'
import dynamic from 'next/dynamic'

// Sanity //
import { loadLatestListingPage } from '@/sanity/lib/store'

// Components //
const LatestListingPage = dynamic(() => import('@/src/components/pages/LatestListingPage'))
const LatestListingPagePreview = dynamic(
  () => import('@/src/components/pages/LatestListingPagePreview')
)

const LatestRoute = async ({ modal }: { modal: React.ReactNode }) => {
  // Load the initial data for the about page.
  const initial = await loadLatestListingPage()

  // If there is no initial data, return null.
  if (!initial) {
    console.error('No data returned for about page')
    return null
  }

  // If draft mode is enabled, return the preview component.
  if (draftMode().isEnabled) return <LatestListingPagePreview initial={initial} />
  return (
    <>
      <LatestListingPage content={initial.data} />
      {modal}
    </>
  )
}

export default LatestRoute

